# Incorrect badge colour in app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

While it might be nice to have even more silver badges, it appears the palette on the iOS app beta release needs to be fixed up:

[image: incorrect bronze badge colour]

It appears to be global, wherever a bronze badge is shown:
[image: another example]

- App Version: 1.6.0
- Device: iPhone 5s (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 10.0 (Build 14A5346a)

Comment: This's the build from TestFlight?

Comment: @luweiqi yes. Version 1.6.0

Comment: that's okay but why it's showing 4 golds in app :D

Comment: @Deepak I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. The OP has four gold badges on Stack Overflow (remember that Meta.SO and SO badges are different), so the badge count as reported by the app is correct.

Comment: ahh my bad. I thought it's you meta SO profile :P

Comment: Reproduced: iPhone 6S, iOS 10, App Version 1.6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.1.

I accidentally reused the silver color when copying/pasting.

Comment: All badges are missing on 1.6.0.3, iOS 10 iPhone 7

Comment: @AshleyMedway [Fixed.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334861/860000)