# Missing badges in beta app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Carrying on from my [previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333820/1255289), I now have no badges at all in the iOS app! Only the numbers are displayed. See screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of problem]

- App Version: 1.6.0.3
- Device: iPhone 5s (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Comment: Cross-site dupe on MSE: [Badges missing/misplaced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284727/310998).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Cross posted on MSE.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284731/235711)

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.4.

This is new to iOS 10.  [The badges were way too big on iOS 10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283115/235711) so I added logic to change things.  Unfortunately I failed to set the offset difference in iOS 10 so it was pulling garbage data from the stack.

See it beautifully illustrated by the static analyzer.

[image: Static analyzer showing that I forgot to assign a value.]

Comment: Thanks; should I be posting bug reports here or meta SE? (A "bug report" button in the app that automatically posts a question to the right place, with appropriate tags, would be cool.)

Comment: @miken32 Our bug tracker searches all meta sites so it doesn't really matter to me where you post it.  MSE is just the most common and I answered the other one first because I saw it on the MSE homepage.  There is a somewhat buried bug reporter on the help screen if you go the menu -> About -> Submit a bug report.